# AS3: angle of reflection

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript

I am stumped on working out the angle of reflection in my AS3 project, I have the formula but the formula relies on you knowing the angle of the object that is reflected against (to work out the perpendicular angle) the trouble is the objects are all at 0 rotation but are shaped differently (e.g the four sides of the stage have a line across them which is at 0 rotation but some are horizontal and some vertical).

How would I work out the angle of reflection purely from the angle of the object that is being reflected, taking into account AS3 returns rotation values between -180 and 180.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: If you plan on using the built-in property rotation, you have to be sure your reflectors are rotated so you can apply your formula. If not, you could override Sprite and add a custom rotation value, set manually at the beginning of your application for each object on the stage.

Comment: @Kodiak but say I have a square in the center of the stage it's rotation would always be the same yet each of it's sides is different. It is not possible to work out reflection of each of it's sides?

Comment: If you want to keep it simple you could separate your cube into 4 triangles, each of them having the right rotation.

Comment: @Kodiak The problem is that just becomes too restrictive and limits me to very basic geometry, i have the idea of breaking a vector down to its outline and then giving each outline an angle where if the start points Y matches the endpoints Y and its X is lower than the endpoints then it is at 0 degrees. But I don't know how to break down a vector drawn in the IDE.

Comment: You can't break down a vector drawn in the IDE. You would have to generate it by code or associate the drawn shape with a virtual simple shape as many physics engine do (http://www.cove.org/ape/).

Comment: @Kodiak this is not exactly true I found the [CDK](http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/downloads/detail?name=CDK%20Documentation%20v15.zip) and inside it is a very useful function called `findAngle`, you can supply it with the bitmapdata of any displayObject and it runs a pixel comparision to determine at what angle the collision occured at. I can then use the object who's colliding rotation to determine the angle of the obstacle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer my question so much as it only works on objects reflecting of horizontal or vertical objects but this function will get you the angle of reflection based upon the rotation of the object which is being reflected...

```
var reflection:int = (incidence > 0) ? 180 - incidence: -180 - incidence;
```

where incidence which is the rotation of the object which is being reflected.